# Installing boost library in /usr/lib: sudo ./boostrap.sh command not found

Tags: ubuntu, boost, installation, bootstrapper

I am trying to install the Boost C++ libraries using [these instructions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install). This is using Ubuntu 10.10. I have unzipped the .zip file in `/usr/lib`, and cd'd to the `boost_1_45_0` folder. I then run:

```
sudo ./boostrap.sh --help
```

And I get the following error:

```
sudo: ./bootstrap.sh: command not found
```

I don't understand why this is, as `bootstrap.sh` is clearly there in the current folder.

Is this because of the location I am installing to, or is it perhaps a command within bootstrap.sh that can't be found? It is a clean Ubuntu install so I am unsure as to why I am getting an error when following instructions so precisely.

Comment: Is `bootstrap.sh` marked executable?

Comment: Aha- no it isn't. It has `-rw-r--r--`. How can I make it executable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Unix, you really want to install from the [tarball](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=7586&package_id=8041), not the `.zip` file. Tarballs preserve Unix permissions.

To make `./bootstrap.sh` executable, issue `chmod 755 bootstrap.sh`.

Comment: Thanks, I redid it from the tarball to ensure everything else went smoothly.